# Drop down selected index changed event not firing event the autopostback = true

Tags: asp.net

Dropdown `selectedindexchanged` event not firing event the autopostback=true and also i tried causes validation to false/true but not luck here is the code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList15" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" 
CausesValidation="false" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="ds_Country" 
DataTextField="Country" style="margin-left:70px;"
DataValueField="CountryId" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
onselectedindexchanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged1">  </asp:DropDownList>
```

code behind is simple like

```
 protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["CountryId"] = ddlCountry.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["CountryId"] = ddlCountry.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }

Comment: This drop down is placed in a page or web control (ascx)?

Comment: Please provide Page_Load even code

Comment: your dropdown name is different in initialization and selectedindexchange

Comment: i changed and tried but same issue